I am trying to understand how to calculate the expected shortage quantity for a normally distributed demand and a given Service level. Loss function?
Service level - 90%
Z = 1.28
Quantity = 7746
Standard Deviation = 343
How should I calculate the expected shortage quantity using the loss function principle for this given data...

The loss function for a standard normal distribution (standard loss function) is defined as:
$$L(z) = \int_{z}^{\infty} (x-z)p(x)dx,$$
where $x$ is normally distributed variable with a mean $\mu$ of $0$ and a standard deviation $\sigma$ of $1$. $p(.)$ is the PDF of the standard normal distribution.
There is also an analytic expression: if you split up the integral and apply integration by substitution and use the mathematical definition of the CDF and PDF of the standard normal distribution, then you can write the loss function as:
$$L(z) = -z(1-P(z))+p(z),$$
where $P(.)$ is the CDF of the standard normal distribution.
The loss function for the normal distribution can then be defined as $\sigma L(z).$
The data you have provided is incomplete though. You have to give the definition of your service level. If I look at your $z$-value and the percentage, I assume you are using the definition of a Cycle Service Level (CSL). In that case, just plug in the $z$-value into these equations and you get the expected shortage quantity.
Note that this loss function is, at best, a very good approximation of the expected shortage quantity. Looking at your data I assume you are using an ordering strategy that uses a reordering point and a fixed order quantity. Please note that using this loss function works only well when your order quantity is relatively large.
The exact calculation would be (with continuous review):
$$\sigma L(z)-\sigma L(z+\frac{Q}{\sigma}),$$
where $Q$ is your order quantity.
